# JailBreak: Open link in safari instead of apps internal web browser?

Tags: jailbreak, ios, ipad, tweaks

Does anyone know if there is a jailbreak tweak that will allow URLs to open in Safari.app, instead of the app internal web browser?
I've been looking around but couldn't find one.

I'm using an iPad 3.

Comment: What iOS are you running?

Comment: iOS 7 with the latest jailbreak

Comment: This might have other implications to it. If you had all UIWebViews open in Safari instead, you'd end up with a lot of applications that simply don't work anymore.